# If $p,q$ are different odd primes, show that $pq \not \mid 2^p+2^q$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I've managed to prove that $p\mid2^{q-1}+1$ and that $q\mid2^{p-1}+1$ if $pq\mid2^p+2^q$.

Also, since $2^{(p-1)(q-1)}\equiv1(mod\ pq)$, and according to Euler Theorem, I can prove that $2^{pq-1}\equiv2^{(p-1)+(q-1)}\equiv-1(mod\ pq)$.

But I have no idea what to do next, can anyone help me out?

Comment: Let $p>q$. Then if $2^p+2^q$ is divisible by $pq$ you'll get also $2^{p-q}-1$ is divisible by $pq$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have that $2^{q-1} \equiv - 1 \pmod p \implies 2^{2q - 2} \equiv 1 \pmod p$. Now let $o_p(2)$ be the order of $2$ in the multiplicative group $(\mathbb{Z}_p)^*$. Then we have that $o_p(2) \mid p-1$ and $o_p(2) \mid 2q-2$. Also we know that $o_p(2) \not \mid q-1$. So let $v_2(n)$ be the power of two in the prime factorization of $n$. For example $v_2(8) = 3$. Then as $o_p(2) \mid 2q-2$ and $o_p(2) \not \mid q-1$ we have that:

$$v_2(o_p(2)) > v_2(q-1)$$

Also as; $o_p(2) \mid p-1$ we have:

$$v_2(p-1) \ge v_2(o_p(2)) > v_2(q-1)$$

Now doing this with the other relation we have that:

$$v_2(q-1) \ge v_2(o_q(2)) > v_2(p-1)$$

But this is a contradiction.

Comment: It's really a good way to consider the power of two in the prime factorization of them, and you have reminded me of that. Thanks a lot for your kind help.